# Can Ebean set global query timeout?

Tags: ebean

I know that for Ebean, we can set query timeout on, for example, `SqlUpdate` using this: http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html#setTimeout(int)

But is there a way that we can set global timeout? That's to say, I can set a global timeout and don't have to set timeout each time.

Comment: The docs have moved https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidoc/10/io/ebean/SqlUpdate.html#setTimeout-int-

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to set a global query timeout.